# Xauthority problem

Tags: rhel, x11, xauth

User1 has his home directory on NFS that's mounted by machine1 and machine2, both of which are running Redhat 6.4.

If I `ssh -Y user1@machine1` and run gedit, I get **"X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication"**. If I do the same on machine2 everything works just fine.

There are multiple people ssh-ed as user1 (yeah I know it's a security problem) to both machines. The .Xauthority and login scripts are the same ($HOME resides on a share) and XAUTHORITY is not defined.

I ran `cat .Xauthority` and I can see multiple entries for both machine1 and machine2.
I can run other GUIs, such as diffuse, on both machines, no problem.

Any ideas what might be the problem?